# Error on AWS Lambda connected to DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting the following error when accessing to a lambda connected to a dynamo table which function is to write on it. The GET method works fine, the problem happens with de PUT method.

> ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when
> calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were
> invalid: Missing the key customer_id in the itemTraceback (most recent
> call last):  File "/var/task/create.py", line 12, in create    return
> todoList.todoList().put_item(event,context)  File
> "/var/task/todoList.py", line 112, in put_item
> table.put_item(Item=item)  File
> "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
> response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)  File
> "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in **call**
> response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args,
> **params)  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
> raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)

Any ideas on how to solve it? Thank you

Comment: It's useful to include error messages and exceptions but you should also include the relevant parts of your source code.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a new item (or in DynamoDB terms: put a new item) in the table.

The error states:

> Missing the key customer_id in the item

That means that the item you are trying to put into your table is missing `customer_id`, as it is probably part of the hash or sort key.

To solve this set `customer_id`.